# Selenium Webdriver gettext() returns empty string

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have the following HTML in my page.

```
<div dojoattachpoint="rowNode" class="dijitTreeRow dijitTreeRowSelected" wairole="presentation" dojoattachevent="onmouseenter:_onMouseEnter, onmouseleave:_onMouseLeave, onclick:_onClick, ondblclick:_onDblClick" role="presentation" title="" style="padding-left: 19px; ">
    <img src="/runtime/explorer.sharedresources/javascript-1.7.22.268034/release/dojo/resources/blank.gif" alt="" dojoattachpoint="expandoNode" class="dijitTreeExpando dijitTreeExpandoLeaf" wairole="presentation" role="presentation"/>
    <span dojoattachpoint="expandoNodeText" class="dijitExpandoText" wairole="presentation" role="presentation">*</span>
    <span dojoattachpoint="contentNode" class="dijitTreeContent" wairole="presentation" role="presentation">
    <img src="/runtime/explorer.sharedresources/javascript-1.7.22.268034/release/dojo/resources/blank.gif" alt="" dojoattachpoint="iconNode" class="dijitIcon dijitTreeIcon criterionFolder" wairole="presentation" role="presentation"/>
    <span dojoattachpoint="labelNode" class="dijitTreeLabel" wairole="treeitem" tabindex="-1" waistate="selected-false" dojoattachevent="onfocus:_onLabelFocus" role="treeitem" aria-selected="true">**My TEXT**</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

This is the code that correctly identifies the element.

```
 List<WebElement> RowNodesList = elementPopup.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@dojoattachpoint =\"rowNode\"]"));       
    for(WebElement RowNode:RowNodesList)
        {
            System.out.println("Left Padding: " + RowNode.getAttribute("style"));                   

            System.out.println("Is Row Node Displayed: " + RowNode.isDisplayed());

            WebElement labelNode = RowNode.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@dojoattachpoint=\"labelNode\"]"));

            boolean IsNodeDisplayed = labelNode.isDisplayed();

            System.out.println("Is Label Node Displayed: " + IsNodeDisplayed);

            String NodeLabel = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) _driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].firstChild.nodeValue",labelNode);
            System.out.println("Row label From javaScript: " + NodeLabel);
            System.out.println("Row label: " + labelNode.getText());
            System.out.println("Row Class: " + labelNode.getAttribute("class"));

        }
```

This is the output generated from the code.

```
Left Padding: PADDING-LEFT: 19px
Is Row Node Displayed: true
Is Label Node Displayed: false
Row label From javaScript: undefined
Row label: 
Row Class: dijitTreeLabel
```

For some reason, an empty string is returned by .getText(). Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Curiously, labelNode.isdisplayed() returns false, even though it is visible on the page.

Edit 2: I have edited my OP to the above to make the problem more clear. So, the text that i want resides in the SPAN tag of the label node, which is a child of the RowNode. RowNode is supposedly displayed, but the label node is not. I think that is why .getText() for the LabelNode is returning an empty string.

Is there any other way I can get the text?

Edit 3: I figured out the problem. It was the xpath search string. 
Instead of

```
WebElement labelNode = RowNode.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@dojoattachpoint=\"labelNode\"]"));
```

the xpath needs to be changed to

```
WebElement labelNode = RowNode.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[@dojoattachpoint=\"labelNode\"]"));
```

I had assumed that "//" will instruct WebDriver to look within the current context. But apparently, it searches within the entire body (which is not intuitive), and returned the first element found which was hidden.
 Adding ".//" instructs it to search within the current context (RowNode).

Thanks Everyone for their help.

Comment: I tried using JavaScript to return the text, but instead if any empty string, it returns "undefined".

<code>
String NodeLabel = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) _driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].firstChild.nodeValue",contentNode);
   System.out.println("Row label From javaScript: " + NodeLabel); </code>

Comment: If it returns undefined then it can't find your element, and it's safe to say your selector is wrong.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas , you were right. OP has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok the only way I could get this to work was using this:

```
var textstring = driver.findElement(global[type](elements)).getAttribute('innerHTML').then(
   function(textstring) {
      console.log(textstring);
})
```

Where globaltype can be webdriver.By.id(), xpath or name.

webdriver.By.css also works.

Answer (score -1):

In your System.out.println statements, you're using 'contentNode' instead of 'labelNode'.  Was this a mistake, or is that declared elsewhere in the code?

In C#, I used the following to properly grab the text:

```
IWebElement labelNode = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@dojoattachpoint=\"labelNode\"]"));
string labelNodeText = labelNode.Text;
```

Answer (score -1):

I want to clarify if the `RowNode` variable is of the type WebDriver and also you must call get text on the correct WebElement.

Try using the following code -

```
  WebElement labelNode = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@dojoattachpoint='labelNode']"));
  System.out.println("Row label: " + labelNode.getText());
  System.out.println("Row label: " + labelNode.getAttribute("class"));
```

If an empty string is being returned for getText() method after this change. It either means that the text for this WebElement is not visible. You can also use an implicitWait statement to make sure that the page loads properly before you attempt to access the WebElement.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Hope this helps you.

Can you tell me if the "MY TEXT" is visible on the page when you open the page on your browser. If it is visible you can get the value using getText() method. If not then try this -

```
 String labelNodeText = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) _driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML",labelNode);
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I have corrected the code in the OP. I am waiting for the page to load completely before making this call, and the element is visible.
The RowNode variable is the parent webelement.

Comment: If RowNode variable is the parent WebElement, then use the code I have edited in my answer. Define the driver as mentioned above and let me know what happens?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. same issue. I don't think synchronization is an issue. Please see the updated OP.

Comment: I checked your code, clearly the labelNode.isDisplayed() returns false. Therefore labelNode.getText() will return an empty string.

Comment: It returns Null. I figured out the solution. OP updated. Thanks for your help.